# Autosuggest search by full name

Tags: sql, sql-server, autosuggest

I've implemented an autosuggest search using jQuery, php and SQL server 2008. I'm looking for people by their name. The name of the person is divided in three fields 'nombres, 'apellido_paterno' and 'apellido_materno'. My autosuggest matches results where one of the three fields looks like the pattern in the input text.

```
  $values = array(':x'=>$data['term'].'%',':y'=>$data['term'].'%',':z'=>$data['term'].'%');
  $sql = "SELECT TOP 10 id_persona, nombres +' '+ apellido_paterno +' '+ apellido_materno AS value 
                FROM personas WHERE nombres LIKE :x OR apellido_paterno LIKE :y OR apellido_materno LIKE :z";
```

So my query is working fine if you search by name or lastname, however if you search by full name there are no matches. So,  how do I add criteria to my query in order to bring full name matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all three are varchar fields, and you are querying a somewhat limited number of records, I would just do:

```
$values = array(':x'=>'%'.$data['term'].'%');
  $sql = "SELECT TOP 10 id_persona, nombres +' '+ apellido_paterno +' '+ apellido_materno AS value 
FROM personas 
WHERE
nombres + ' ' + apellido_paterno + ' ' + apellido_materno LIKE :x";
```

Comment: I just had to add a whitespace between fields but your answer worked fine. Thanks